# Access Windows 10 localhost from OSX using Parallels

Tags: windows, macos, windows-10, parallels

I'm running a Windows 10 VM using Parallels. I'm building an API on the windows machine and a mobile app on OSX. I need to call the Windows localhost from OSX in order to test out my API calls. Is this possible with Win 10 and if so what are the steps?

Comment: Just use the guest IP address you get from Parallels and use it in the host browser. If it doesn't work, check out [this FAQ entry](http://kb.parallels.com/en/120446).

Comment: Is it possible to access IIS express this way though? I've updated my host file and turned off the file wall and can't seem to connect to it.

Comment: Actually it doesn't look like that is possible based off of this article https://www.getdonedone.com/accessing-your-windows-development-environment-from-osx/

Comment: This is for a specific service, Visual Studio Deployment, which blocks all requests from other hosts (this includes the OSX machine). From what you write, it looks you have your own API you want to test, so this is not applicable here.

Comment: I think if I host my api on standard IIS I should be able to call the services from the Host since IIS Express blocks everything. I'll create an answer with the details if it works out.

Comment: If you can't change your server's settings to allow connection from the VM-host's IP (although this limitation wouldn't make sense for a server anyway), then you would need a local proxy which listens on another port so that your server sees only the localhost as sender.

Comment: @CherryDT so what you're saying is, due to me trying to call my API from the host rather than just trying to access local host directly I'm basically unable to do what I need to do?

Comment: No; depends what it is exactly which you need to do. I mentioned that it should normally be possible to access the inner "localhost" by using the VM's internal IP from the outside, provided that the Windows firewall is configured correctly. If not, and your server blocks all requests coming from IPs other than `127.0.0.1`, then it should be possible to change this constraint in the server as said, or if this is not possible such as with the Visual Studio Deployment server in your example, then it should be possible to install a local reverse proxy in the VM and suppress the forwarded IP header